# Copy-Paste "unexpanded" text in Microsoft Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2005. 
How do I copy and paste the text that has been outlined?
I would like to copy one list of name and initialization of the method/functions without the actual coding.

I have googled around but unfortunately could not find it.

From Microsoft documents below, what I want is to paste the "unexpanded" region:

"The Undo and Redo commands on the Edit menu affect these actions. The Copy, Cut, Paste, and drag-and-drop operations retain outlining information, but not the state of the collapsible region. **For example, when you copy a region that is collapsed, the Paste operation will paste the copied text as an expanded region.**"

Comment: Are you sure you mean Visual Studio 2005?

Comment: Yea. Thats the current version that I am using. But if your solution can be used only for latest version, I am also okay. Thanks!